# Ansible mail module not working with office 365

Tags: email, smtp, ansible

I am trying to send send an email from ansible

If I try it with gmail it works perfectly, However If I try with office 365 its not working.

Below is my Playbook.

```
---
  - name: Mail Sendig using Ansible
    hosts: localhost
    tasks:
      - name: Mail sending using Mail Module
        mail:
          host: "smtp.office365.com"
          port: 587
          username: "dcalert@mycompany.com"
          password: "mypasswd"
          to: "Jon Snow <jon.snow@mycompany.com>"
          subject: "Ansible"
          body: "Hello from Ansible"
          secure: starttls
```

I am getting below error

```
ASK [Send email]
*******************************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full 
traceback, use -vvv. The error was: SMTPSenderRefused: (501, '5.1.7 
Invalid address', 'root')
fatal: [localhost -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, 
"failed": true, "msg": "Failed to send mail to 
jon.snow@mycompany.com: (501, '5.1.7 Invalid address', 
'root')", "rc": 1}
```

Comment: not ansible fault, look at the error message `Failed to send mail to 
jon.snow@mycompany.com: (501, '5.1.7 Invalid address', 
'root')`

Comment: @BaptisteMille-Mathias, same thing worked with gmail, If you try sending email to same email from gmail, it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing `from`parameter...

Take a look here: [Ansible Mail Module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/mail_module.html)

It says the parameter `from` defaults to root. Since you're not setting it, mail server says its invalid. Probably gmail doesnt handle it the same way as office365.

Give this a try...

```
---
  - name: Mail Sendig using Ansible
    hosts: localhost
    tasks:
      - name: Mail sending using Mail Module
        mail:
          host: "smtp.office365.com"
          port: 587
          username: "dcalert@mycompany.com"
          password: "mypasswd"
          from: "dcalert@mycompany.com"
          to: "Jon Snow <jon.snow@mycompany.com>"
          subject: "Ansible"
          body: "Hello from Ansible"
          secure: starttls
```

Comment: I tried that too it didn't worked. `The error was: socket.gaierror: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_za5Epf/ansible_module_mail.py\", line 386, in <module>\n    main()\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_za5Epf/ansible_module_mail.py\", line 257, in main\n    code, smtpmessage = smtp.connect(host, port=port)\n `

Comment: `in main\n    code, smtpmessage = smtp.connect(host, port=port)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py\", line 316, in connect\n    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py\", line 291, in _get_socket\n    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py\", line 557, in create_connection\n    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):\nsocket.gaierror: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 0}`